# htaccess RedirectMatch regular expression for URL?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

On my Wordpress blog, I used to have a plugin that I no longer need. The plugin used to create a bunch of URLs that looked like this:

`http://tambnguyen.com/manage-subscriptions?srp=532&sra=s`

with the postID being 532. How do I redirect the query strings so that the above URL will redirected to:

`http://tambnguyen.com/?p=532`

I've tried a few method without any luck (there's an optional "/" after "manage-subscriptions"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/manage-subscriptions/?\?srp=(\d{1,5})(.*)$ http://tambnguyen.com/\?p=$1
</IfModule>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^srp=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^manage-subscriptions/?$ /?p=%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do with RedirectMatch instead of rewriting it?

Comment: As per my knowledge Redirect and RedirectMatch cannot redirect to a URL with a querystring therefore it is better to use mod_rewrite which is much more advanced and feature rich.

Comment: I've added the below code onto my .htaccess file, no luck. Am I missing something?

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^srp=([^&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^manage-subscriptions/?$ /?p=%1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Two things: 1. Have you loaded mod_redir module in httpd.cond? 2. Can you comment out `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` and try again?

Comment: 1.) this isn't my server, I have no access to httpd.cond and 2.) Yes, tried that, still doesn't work :(

Comment: I wrote requirements in my 1st line that you need to enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess. Please make sure both are enabled. Above rule, I have tested at my server and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. However, given that this is a Wordpress self-hosted site, one can assume both aforementioned conditions are met.
Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: You can quickly test both. First put some junk text and it should generate 500 error. 2nd put some very simple RewriteRule and see if that works.

Comment: I've finally figured out why your solution didn't work for me in the first place. I had your snippet BELOW the RewriteRule for Wordpress, so the query string was already matched and thrown with a 404 before it could get to your code. After I moved your code to be ABOVE Wordpress RewriteRule, it's working as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah I didn't see `wordpress` in the tags otherwise I would have suggested you that. Glad that it worked out eventually.